# Fetch data from MongoDB query in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, find, response

I am trying to fetch data from find() method, to use the data outside the find() method. I want to use the data in JSON response. This code didn't work well. The data is not defined outside the find() method.
HOW COULD I USE THE DATA IN THE RESPONSE?

```js
var path = '';
var direct = '';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/serverad';

MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
  assert.equal(err,null);

 db.collection("adchar").find(
    { target_gender: 'female' },
    {ad_path:1,ad_direct:1, _id:0}).toArray(function(err,docs){
      callback(docs);
      assert.equal(err,null);
      path =docs[0].ad_path;
      direct =docs[0].ad_direct;
                  }); 
     });
  

exports.get = function(req, res) {  
res.writeHead(200 , { 'content-Type':'application/json'})
var myObj = {
AdUrl:path
,dirURL : direct, 
};
res.end(JSON.stringify(myObj));
};
```

Comment: Is this the full code that you have? At what point does your `exports.get` method get invoked?

Comment: No this is not the full code, the exports.get method  in router.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do this staff . The code is incomplete**

```
var path = '';
var direct = '';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/serverad';

var fetchData =  function(callback){

MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
  assert.equal(err,null);

 db.collection("adchar").find(
    { target_gender: 'female' },
    {ad_path:1,ad_direct:1, _id:0}).toArray(function(err,docs){
      callback(err ,docs);
      assert.equal(err,null);
      path =docs[0].ad_path;
      direct =docs[0].ad_direct;
                  }); 
     });
}; 

exports.get = function(req, res) {  

fetchData (function(error,result){
    if(error){
        // do error staff here
    } else{
    res.writeHead(200 , { 'content-Type':'application/json'})
    var myObj = {
    AdUrl:path
    ,dirURL : result, 
    };
    res.end(JSON.stringify(myObj));
    }
});

};
```

Comment: Thank you, there the data appear, but in incorrect format- see the next comment -,It must be as JSON file output.

Comment: {"AdUrl":"","dirURL":[{"ad_path":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/5d/35/74/5d35749e29ed87fc9d38caedcdfb6b96--kids-girls-baby-kids.jpg","ad_direct":"https://myjoyflowershop.com/"}]}

Comment: can you tell me when you print `myObj` what you get ?

Comment: The output in the previous comment, but now I try to print result[0] , and it is work well, as I need. Thanks for all who help me.

Comment: Marks the answer if you get you solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide you a good answer without refatcoring your whole code. I've separate the logic of the app in different files

**db.js**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

// these variables are not set until the connecion is established, any attempt
// to use them before that will, most likely, throw an error;
exports.client = undefined;
exports.database = undefined;
exports.adCharCollection = undefined;

exports.connect = async function connect(host, dbName) {
  exports.client = await MongoClient.connect(host);
  exports.database = exports.client.db(dbName);
  exports.adCharCollection = exports.database.collection("adchar");
}
```

**model.js**

```
const db = require('./db');

exports.getResults = async function getResults(gender) {
  const docs = db.adCharCollection
    .find({ target_gender: gender }, { ad_path: 1, ad_direct: 1, _id: 0 })
    .limit(1)
    .toArray();

  if (!docs.length) {
    return null;
  }

  const doc = docs[0];

  return { AdUrl: doc.ad_path, dirURL: doc.ad_direct };
}
```

**controller.js**

```
const { getResults } = require('./model');

exports.get = async function get(req, res) {
  try {
    const result = await getResults("female");

    res.writeHead(200, { "content-Type": "application/json" });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
  } catch (err) {
    res.writeHead(500, { "content-Type": "application/json" });
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      error: true,
      message: err.message,
      stack: err.stack.split('\n') // the stack only for development purposes
    }));
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const { connect } = require('./db');
const { get } = require('./controller');

const PORT = 3000;
const MONGO_HOST = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const MONGO_DB = 'serverad';

async function main() {
  // we first need to connect to mongo before doing anything
  await connect(MONGO_HOST, MONGO_DB);

  // set the request handler
  const server = http.createServer(get);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }

      console.log(`server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
      resolve();
    });
  });

  return server;
}

main().catch(err => console.log(err.stack));
```